# tensorflow.keras.utils.plot_model not working correctly

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, plot

I've just used the tf.keras.utils.plot_model and the following diagram appeared:

[image: diagram appeared]

The right part of the diagram shows the input and output shapes with a vertical split, but it should be an horizontal split to fit with the "intput:" and "output:" cells at its left.

[image]

code line :

```
# Import the required libraries.
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

input_shape = Input(shape=(128,128,3), name='input')
conv1 = Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=6, strides=2, padding='valid', activation='relu', name='conv1')(input_shape)
flt = Flatten()(conv1)
shared = Dense(64)(flt)
sub1 = Dense(16)(shared)
out1 = Dense(3, activation='softmax', name='gait')(sub1)
model = Model(inputs=input_shape, outputs=out1)


plot_model(model=model, show_shapes=True)
```

The result you want :

[image: Result]

Comment: Can you update your question with your code?

Comment: @Djinn I modified it,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for(Horizontal Split of Input and Output values) can be achieved in the earlier version of `TensorFlow 2.7`.

Please install the `TensorFlow 2.7` using the below code, restart the kernel and then try running the same above code:

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.7
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I've looked at this for a few hours now and I've recreated the issue. I can recreate both plotted models how you show (vertical and horizontal) but I can't control it directly. The only real difference I can see is that the `plot_model()` results you're looking for is when the model is built using `Functional API`. Using `Sequential API` produces the graph you *don't* want.

So pretty much try recreating your model using `Functional API` instead of `Sequential API`. You shouldn't see any difference in performance. I would've redone your model using `Functional API` but there's no code to redo. If you want, you can play around with `keras.utils.vis_utils.py.model_to_dot()` to see if you can get the `Functional API` output for all model types. I might update this answer later with the changes if I find them. Looking at that file, and also comparing to generated plots, I'm positive it's when the function checks if the model is `sequential.Sequential` or `functional.Functional`.

Comment: I created my model using Functional API, I added the code